# Microsoft bot does not show image correctly

Tags: botframework

Generating images for ThumbnailCard this way:

```
ThumbnailCard thumbnailCard = new ThumbnailCard()
                        {
                            Title = model[i].Title,
                            Images = Helper.CreateImages(model[i])
                        };
```

In the Helper class I have this function:

```
public static List<CardImage> CreateImages(Model model)
{
     List<CardImage> ListImages = new List<CardImage>();
     ListImages.Add(new CardImage(url: model.Logo));
     return ListImages;
}
```

**The result**

[image: image not shows]

When the image link is copied and pasted in the address bar, image shows up correctly.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you share the image link you are using?

Comment: What channel are you using and what image format?. I realized today that e.g. facebook is not happy (on the mobile clients) for svgs. I haven't had problems with pngs, so far.